# Failing to fetch data when visiting page via link in Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, fetch-api, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt3 and have the index.vue page with a useFetch hook as such

```
<script setup>    
    const { data: trips } = await useFetch("/trips.json", { server: true });
    const trending = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    const seasonalTrips = trips._rawValue.filter((t) => t.id in trending);
</script>
```

Now I have setup a custom error page and when I visit localhost:3000

> 500
>
> Ooooops!
>
> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filter')
>
> Go home

But when I click go home, the page works fine

This is true for other pages as well, where this type of fetching is taking place

So, overall I have observed that my problem is : When I visit a page through typing out the link in the browser I get this error but if I am being redirected to that page from within my application via a NuxtLink. the fetching works fine

How do I fix this very odd issue

Comment: Try using `trips.data` in `trips._rawValue`  and `{server: true}` by default so you don't need to do it. You can instead use `{key: unique_name}`. One more suggestion use computed property for filtering the reactive data.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code main problem is the filter function. The `t.id in trending` does not work correctly.

I have refactored your code below like this & I think It working as you need

```
<script setup>
const { data: trips } = await useFetch(
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
);

const trending = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
const seasonalTrips = trips._rawValue.filter((t) => trending.includes(t.id));

// Use this way I think its better
const st = computed(() => {
  return trips.value.filter((t) => {
    return trending.includes(t.id);
  });
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ seasonalTrips }}</pre>
    <pre>{{ st }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here's the [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-uumpzk?file=app.vue)